# ssh multi interface

Tags: linux, ssh

I have 2 interfaces

```
eth0 10.0.0.163
eth1 10.0.0.164
```

There are two machines are connected from per interface

```
Machine 1 to eth0 with address 10.0.0.160
Machine 2 to eth1 with address 10.0.0.161
```

I want to connect from each interface to each machine but it connects to Machine 1 but not to Machine 2.
I tried ssh option bind with

```
ssh -b 10.0.0.164 10.0.0.161
```

but not responded.How can be achievable?

Comment: Are both machine reachable? What does `ping`ing them tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be because as soon as you put an IP address like `10.0.0.163` onto an interface, a route is added for that network out of that interface. If you need to indicate that a specific address should be reached via  specific interface then you will need a static route to it, like this:

```
# ip route add 10.0.0.161/32 dev eth1
```

Note the /32 for a single IPv4 address route.

You could also maybe do it with source routing, iptables trickery and so on, but I think a static route is the most simple and obvious way.

As an aside, it is a bad idea to two interfaces onto the same network, so `10.0.0.164` should probably have a netmask that makes sure it isn't on the same network as `10.0.0.163`, e.g. `255.255.255.255`.